# Decision tree error : replacement has 625 rows, data has 266

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm fairly new to DS, particularly solving error issues that pop up. Any help would be greatly appreciated to explain the below please:

I set up a decision tree ML:

```
training_tree <- rpart(formula = Target ~ ., data = training[,-1], # removed first column as not just ID method = "class", minbucket = 5, cp = 0, model = TRUE)
```

Pruned it:

```
ptree <- prune(training_tree, cp = 0.002, "CP") # based on CP feedback
```

Created prediction on training data:

```
training$prediction <- predict(ptree, data = training, type = "class")
```

Tried to use on test data:

```
testing$prediction <- predict(ptree, data = testing2[,-1], # have also removed first column type = "class")
```

Then I get the below error:

```
Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, prediction, value = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, : replacement has 625 rows, data has 266
```

I understand that my training data had 625 rows, and my testing data has 266.

How do I fix? What's the reason this pops up so I can avoid in the future?

Comment: You need `testing$prediction <- predict(ptree, newdata = testing2[,-1]` (not data = ...)  Please see `help(predict.tree)`

Comment: perfect, thank you !